# what is time complexity O(n) for replace function using thrice in Python

Tags: python-3.x, replace, time-complexity, big-o, boyer-moore

I am trying to find the time complexity(Big O) of str.replace() inbuilt function in python

I know for *worst-case time is O(n*m)* to find a substring but what *if we use replace thrice* in one line

```
newstr = str1.replace(char1,'*').replace(char2,char1).replace("*",char2)
```

I'm trying to swap char1 and char2 in some string, the alternate code is using for loop which is O(n) time complexity.
But for the above code, will the Big O become 3 times more, or will become n^3?
does that make sense?

Comment: What did you find when you measured it?

Comment: it would still be `O(n)` running it 3 times one after the other does not make it exponential. So the number of iterations would be n x 3. or O(3n), but generally such constants dont get considered when N becomes large, so they are normally dropped so it would still be O(n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But for the above code, will the Big O become 3 times more, or will
> become n^3?

Using Big-O notation to quantify running time means ignoring constant factors by definition. That is, the triple-replace version may have a higher constant factor than a single hand-coded loop that does the swap but they are both still O(n).

The triple-replace version of the swap will not be O(n^3).